# Atribuir Valores de acordo com as datas em array

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Possuo os seguintes objetos retornando em valores:

```
duasSemanas:
2021-02-18: {TOTAL: 20, OUTROS: 8, VALIDOS: 12, MEDIA: 841.8600000000001}
2021-02-19: {TOTAL: 20, OUTROS: 6, VALIDOS: 11, MEDIA: 774.84}
2021-02-22: {TOTAL: 21, OUTROS: 10, VALIDOS: 12, MEDIA: 772.55}
2021-02-23: {TOTAL: 19, OUTROS: 7, VALIDOS: 12, MEDIA: 1029.3799999999999}

primeiroTrimestre:
2020-03-10: {VALIDOS: 13}
2020-03-11: {VALIDOS: 11}
2020-03-12: {VALIDOS: 7}
2020-03-13: {VALIDOS: 10}
2020-03-14: {VALIDOS: 11}
```

E estou atribuindo as datas a um array como mostra abaixo:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$.post("./chart.php", function(dados, status){

var valores = JSON.parse(dados);

    var diasDuasSemanas = [];
    var diasPrimeiro = [];
    var diasSegundo = [];
    var diasTerceiro = [];
    var diasUltimo = [];

    for (var d in valores['duasSemanas'])
    {
      diasDuasSemanas.push(d);
    }

    for (var p in valores['primeiroTrimestre'])
    {
      diasPrimeiro.push(p);
    }

    . . .
```

Minha dúvida é: Como eu acesso as ASSOCIAÇÕES Total, Validos, Outros... e atribuir elas a um array?

var arrayTotal = []

Por Exemplo: diasPrimeiro(todos os dias) : arrayTotal(todos os totais de acordo com o dia)

Me ajudem por favor, é de extrema importância!

Comment: Seu primeiro trecho não é um JSON válido, então a linha `JSON.parse(dados)` daria erro. Tem certeza que é aquela informação que você recebe?

Comment: Está sim, quando coloco no gráfico Chart aparecem as datas também, copiei o retorno direto do console

Comment: Mas ele não é um JSON válido, então seu código não faz muito sentido. Poderia fazer um [mcve] demonstrando o problema?

Comment: Só preciso acessar o terceiro array dentro dos outros 2 anteriores